# Trouble getting time interval between two NSDate() instances in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, time, nsdate, intervals

I'm relatively new to Swift. I'm working on a mobile app heavily dependent on a UITextView. My desired behavior is when a user does a quick double tap on the spacebar, the cursor will jump ahead 5 spaces. I'm attempting to accomplish this by timing the interval between space presses using NSDate(), but am having no success. I'm able to detect the double tap, but just can't detect a quick one (under 0.1 seconds). Would love some help about what I am doing wrong here.

UPDATE: I think the issue is in the logic. spaceTime and timeTwo seem to always get close to the same values. I guess I want to know how to make spaceTime a static number after a single space press.

My code is as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    func characterBeforeCursor()->String?
    {
        if let cursorRange=mainTextBox.selectedTextRange
        {
            if let newPosition = mainTextBox.position(from: cursorRange.start, offset: -1) {

                let range = mainTextBox.textRange(from: newPosition, to: cursorRange.start)
                return mainTextBox.text(in: range!)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text==" "
        {
            let spaceTime=NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

            if characterBeforeCursor()==" "
            {
                let timeTwo=NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

                if(Double(timeTwo)-Double(spaceTime)>0.1)
                {
                    mainTextBox.text="it worked"
                }

                mainTextBox.text="hello"
            }
        }

        mainTextBox.textColor=UIColor.green
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logic does not work. At the point where `timeTwo` and `spaceTime` are compared, both of them have just been set to the current time, which means that they are (almost) equal.

Comment: That's what I figured. I tried printing the difference between the two times out and they were ridiculously small (something like .000054328875). I'm stuck on how to fix it though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Besides needing to change your logic to make this work, keep in mind that when a user double-taps the space key, iOS will likely replace the first space with a period never giving you the chance to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: The double space function works fine (I can easily get the "hello" text to print). My issue is getting the "it worked" to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic a all wrong. You need to check if the user has tapped a space and save the time that this happened. Then you need to check if the previous character was also a space and compare the latest time with the previous time.

Something like the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    var previousSpaceTimestamp: Date?

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == " " {
            let now = Date()
            if let last = previousSpaceTimestamp {
                if now.timeIntervalSince(last) < 0.1 {
                    // User has tapped two spaces in less than 0.1 seconds
                    // update text field as desired

                    return false
                }
            }

            // Store time of this space
            previousSpaceTimestamp = now
        } else {
            // Not a space, reset timestamp
            previousSpaceTimestamp = nil
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Note that there is no need for your `characterBeforeCursor` method.

Also note that you should use `Date`, not `NSDate`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

First I would extend Date to add the function below.

```
extension Date {

  // Returns the amount of nanoseconds from another date
  func nanoSeconds(from date: Date) -> Int {
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.nanosecond], from: date, to: self).nanosecond ?? 0
  }
```

Next try the code below.

```
var previousTapDate: Date?

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text==" " {
        let spaceTime = Date()

        if characterBeforeCursor() == " " {
              if previousTapDate == nil {
                    previousTapDate = dateNow
                  } else {
                    let timeDifference = spaceTime.nanoSeconds(from: previousTapDate!)
                     if timeDifference <= 10000000 {
                        mainTextBox.text="it worked"
                        } else {
                        mainTextBox.text="hello"
                        }
                      }
                    }
    previousTapDate = spaceTime
    mainTextBox.textColor=UIColor.green
    return true
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the `nanoSeconds` just to see if the difference between two `Date` instances is less than 0.1 seconds.